# Regex - Find string in line but replace another string in the same line

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I have problem with find and replace in Perl regex syntax:

I have the following lines:

```
FILEGROUP [PAYMENT_MGMT](NAME = [PAYMENT_MGMT], FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DatabaseName)_PAYMENT_MGMT.ndf', FILEGROWTH = 102400 KB)

LOG ON (NAME = [SQL_log], FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)$(DatabaseName)_log.ldf', SIZE = 5012 KB, MAXSIZE = 2097152 MB, FILEGROWTH = 102400 MB) COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS
```

SO i have to find string **SQL_log** but replace only **SIZE =** with **SIZE = 1024**

How can i achieve this with regex PCRE ?

Comment: So at the end the following line should be: LOG ON (NAME = [SQL_log], FILENAME = '$(DefaultLogPath)$(DatabaseName)_log.ldf', SIZE = **1024** KB, MAXSIZE = 2097152 MB, FILEGROWTH = 102400 MB) COLLATE Slovenian_CI_AS

Comment: Just match and capture everything before the value you need to change and just match the text you want to replace.

Comment: Yes that's my question :) how can i do that :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Capture everything before the target and put it back in the replace:

```
$x =~ s/^(.*?SQL_log.*?SIZE = )\d+/${1}1024/;
```

---

Test code:

```
$x = "foo SQL_log bar SIZE = 5012 baz";
$x =~ s/^(.*?SQL_log.*?SIZE = )\d+/${1}1024/;
print $x;
```

Output:

```
foo SQL_log bar SIZE = 1024 baz
```

Answer (score 2):

Once again all the solutions are cramming everything into a single regex. I don't understand why people do this; it doesn't happen with any other part of the language

This is much more clearly written as

```
if ( /NAME \s* = \s* \[SQL_log\]/x ) {

    s/SIZE \s* = \s* \K \d+/1024/x;

}
```

Comment: Fair enough. Just one quibble -- you need `\b` before both NAME and SIZE to ensure that e.g. FILENAME and MAXSIZE are not matched.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

Search:

```
(IGP_log.*?\bSIZE\b\s=)(\s[0-9]+)
```

Replace:

```
\1 1024
```

or

```
${1} 1024
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed that you won't ever have more than one SQL_log record on the same line, or that SQL_log LOG records always have "NAME =" AND "SIZE =" in that order, the following ought to be a safe solution:

```
s/\b(NAME\s*=\s*\[SQL_log\].+?\bSIZE\s*=\s*)[^,)]*/${1}1024 KB/
```

If you can't guarantee that "NAME =" and "SIZE =" will ALWAYS be in that order but you CAN guarantee there will never be more than one per line, you will need this in addition:

```
s/\b(SIZE\s*=\s*)[^,]*(.+?\bNAME\s*=\s*\[SQL_log\])/${1}1024 KB$2/
```